# How to attach a File to a Contact?

Tags: files

One can attach a file to an Activity, but is it possible to attach a file to a Contact ? How ?

Then, if the file is an image (jpg or png, ...) how to display it ?

(I am using CiviCRM/Drupal + Webform + Views)

Comment: Where do you want the image to be displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use webform and views, create a custom field in CIVIcrm, an image field, it will then be available from the Webform interface to be added.

Then select that particular field to be displayed on the view.

Comment: Thank you all ; I actually use Webform and Views, but did not know that it was so simple. Unfortunately, I can only click one answer, but all of them are useful.

Comment: Hi Jacques - yes you can only 'accept' on answer but you should be able to +1 all of them

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is to use the Documents extension: https://civicrm.org/extensions/documents. This will allow you to add documents to contacts and show them on a separate tab.

Comment: Totally recommend this module - has done wonders for us

Comment: however from memory it only works if you are using CiviCase doesnt it?. We have scoped out extending it to work purely with Activities but client is hesitating.

Comment: I do not think it only works with Cases @petednz-fuzion but I have not seen it since about 2016 :-)

Answer (score 4):

A basic option to store a file is to create a custom field of type File.  Not sure how well that plays though with webforms/views but easy enough to try.

Comment: It would not cause an issue for either Views or Webform. Ie if the workflow is, look at a view, click through to a Webform, add file ... then that would work just fine. if alternatively you need the View or Webform loading the file then i also don't think that is problematic